# cxxbridge error on cargo contract

Tags: ink, contracts

I was developing things yesterday and during that development I had briefly a file named "asset_extension.rs", that I renamed later. I finished that development, tests passed and everyone was happy. This involved chain extensions, to quite some ink! interaction.

Today whenever I do `cargo contract` related stuff i receive

```
 --- stderr
  cxxbridge: Failed to read file `src/assets_extension`
```

`cargo contract new whatever && cd whatever && cargo test` yields this. Lastly i removed `cargo-contract` to install it again and now I can't even install it with the same error.

Tried cargo clean / update / remove all the things, nothing helped :-(

Answer (score 1):

`grep -rnw . -e "assets_extension"` in .cargo and raw deleting everything that occured solved this.